# Get last selected value of a databound asp.NET checkboxlist with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist, selectedvalue

I have a databound Checkboxlist in asp.NET with DataTextField and DataValueField.

Now if i select a single item in that list, i need to have the value of only that item.

I found lots of solutions to find the values of all selected items but that is not what i need.
 The only value i need is the one i justed selected or deselected.

Is there a way to get this value with jQuery code? For example in an alert like in the code below.

```
$("#checkboxlist").click(function () {
            alert('value of the item that just got (de)selected');
        });
```

Thanks alot!

UPDATE:
This is the html part:

```
<span id="checkboxlist">
    <input id="checkboxlist_0" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist$checkboxlist_0" value="11" />
    <label for="checkboxlist_0">Item 1</label><br />

    <input id="checkboxlist_1" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist$checkboxlist_1" value="12" />
    <label for="checkboxlist_1">Item 2</label><br />

    <input id="checkboxlist_2" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist$checkboxlist_2" value="13" />
    <label for="checkboxlist_2">Item 3</label><br />

    <input id="checkboxlist_3" type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist$checkboxlist_3" value="14" />
    <label for="checkboxlist_3">Item 4</label><br />
</span>
```

Comment: I put the Html part of the checkboxlist in my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, that's the `asp` part, could you show the Html that it's being generated by that?

Comment: I guess i misunderstood, sorry for that. The new update contains the generated Html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work ([Attribute Ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)):

```
$('[id$="checkboxlist"] input').click(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
});
```

`asp:CheckBoxList`  will be rendered as some element (in your case it should be `span`) with ID like `ctl00_contenttop_checkboxlist` and inputs inside it. Code above will find all inputs inside element with ID that ends with `checkboxlist` and will be fired when one of those elements is clicked.

But attribute ends with could be slow, so it could be better to do something like this:

```
$("#<%=checkboxlist.ClientID %> input").click(function () {
                alert($(this).val());
});
```

`checkboxlist.ClientID` will return ID of wrapper element on client side.

**UPD:**

According to your HTML, it looks like ClientID is not needed (as it looks like you are using .net 4 with `ClientIDMode` enabled). In that case you can simply use:

```
$("#checkboxlist input").click(function () {
                alert($(this).val());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2BX/)